# Sort list containing both lists and scalars

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of lists and scalars like this:

```
a = [[[3, -4.241], 9]
[[6, -4.187], 1]
[[2, -4.215], 4]
[[9, -4.238], 5]]
```

which I need to sort by descending order of the first argument of the first list, like this:

```
[[[9, -4.238], 5]
[[6, -4.187], 1]
[[3, -4.241], 9]
[[2, -4.215], 4]]
```

This doesn't work:
    sorted(a,key=lambda x: x[0][0])

What's the proper way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is it always 1 list and 1 scalar? Does the list always have 2 values? Then a tuple would fit better.

Comment: it is always 1 list and 1 scalar indeed, and the list always have 2 values. A tuple would indeed fit better, but, if possible, i'd rather not have to change it.

Comment: your solution works fine for me: http://goo.gl/KCGPrd. What is your output and what did you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> help(sorted)
sorted(iterable, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) --> new sorted list
```

You have to fix the direction:

```
sorted(pareto, key=lambda x: x[0][0], reverse=True)
```

Comment: alternative just invert the key: `key=lambda x: -x[0][0]`